Writing query in SQL
I am trying to group a set of data in Google BigQuery and I wrote this query. It keeps bringing out error message. Please, can someone help correct the query or guide me on how to write it correctly. Thank you.
SELECT 
    started_at,
    ended_at,
    ended_at - started_at AS ride_length,
    AVG(ended_at - started_at) AS avg_ride_length,
FROM 
    `st-project-413711.Cyclistic_bike_share.april_2020` 
GROUP BY 
    member_casual
LIMIT 1000


Welcome to Stack Overflow .... let me suggest that you have a read at the following article:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
As I read your question, there appears to be opportunity to improve it.  Specifically, you said that there is an error but you gave no indication of what the text/message/description of the error might be.   Please consider the time of those who may want to respond.  If you don't, its likely your question will simply be skipped.

You have GROUP BY clause that doesn't correspond to SELECT clause.
Column member_casual doesn't exist among columns in SELECT.
First three columns from the SELECT doesn't exist among columns in GROUP BY.
Maybe there are other errors, but at least you have this.
Providing the error text would be nice.
